# Non-sense errors with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Yo world!";
}
```

I get multiple errors of `undefined refrence to '__chktsk_ms'`. Why?

Comment: You seem to be using an old version of the compiler. Try upgrading it.

Comment: The newest one get giving me no Disk errors so I thought downgrading might help :/

Comment: It's because it *used* to have a symbol called `__chktsk_ms`, so you're using an old compiler that adds references to that symbol, but got newer libraries, which don't have it anymore. =/

Comment: There's clearly something inconsistent with your current mingw setup. Uninstall and completely remove your existing mingw and download a recent one from [mingw64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) or [tdm-gcc](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/).